# Migrating MySQL procedure to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So I'm migrating data from a `MySQL (MariaDB)` to a `SQL Server 2019`, and all tables migrated fine, but the stored procedures didn't, and I would like to know what causes this error, since I've never used SQL Server only MySQL.

My ERROR log form `SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL`

```
Starting Phase #1
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.AddTestCaseRequirement ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.AddTestResultRequirement ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestResults ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestRun ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestRunWithTestJob ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateJiraLink ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTarget ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestCase ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestJob ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestResultsJiraLink ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuite ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCaseLink ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCollection ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCollectionLink ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateVersion ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestJob ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestResults ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestRun ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new function SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.IsTemporaryName ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.SetStatusName ...
  ... sql execution failed
Loading to database new procedure SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.SetTestJobFinished ...
  ... sql execution failed
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.AddTestCaseRequirement
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.AddTestResultRequirement
 Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestResults
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestRun
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.BeginTestRunWithTestJob
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateJiraLink
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTarget
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestCase
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestJob
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestResultsJiraLink
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuite
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCaseLink
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCollection
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateTestSuiteCollectionLink
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateVersion
 Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestJob
 Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestResults
 Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestRun
 Errors: Invalid column name '__'.
Invalid column name '__'.
Synchronization error: Invalid column name '__'.
Invalid column name '__'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.IsTemporaryName
 Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.SetStatusName
 Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.SetTestJobFinished
Synchronization operation is complete.
```

**Error 1**

An example of one of the failing MySQL stored procedures `BeginTestRun`

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (`id`,`StartTime`, `TestJobId`)
  VALUES (NULL,StartTime,TestJobId);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

The above one had this error:

> Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

What should I write instead of `NULL`? and why isn't this allowed?

**Error 2**

Another one `EndTestRun`

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `EndTestRun`(TestRunId INT, EndTime DATETIME)
BEGIN
  UPDATE TestRuns
  SET `EndTime` = EndTime
  WHERE ID = TestRunId;
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Had this error

> Synchronization error: Incorrect syntax near '`'. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.EndTestRun
> Errors: Invalid column name '__'.

I don't really see where `__` should be?

**Error 3**

And another different one is `CreateVersion`

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`edmetrics`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateVersion`(varName varchar(100), Version varchar(100), TargetId INT)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Versions(`id`,`Name`,`Version`,`TargetId`)
  VALUES (NULL,varName,Version,TargetId);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

With the error

> Synchronization error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values. On: SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.CreateVersion
> Errors: Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Should **`** just be removed, why isn't it allowed?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96551d80-c5ce-405f-8a28-332103a50ce9/sql-server-compatibility-null-values-in-identity-column?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: There has been a lot of effort put into answers here. If you infd one of them helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** SQL Server does not accepts accents (which are specific to MySQL) to delimits SQL identifiers (name of table, column, procedure... and so on). You must use SQL ISO standard double quote or specific SQL Server delimiter (square brackets) or nothing if your SQL identifier conforms to the standard. So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun` ...
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE DEFINER="root`@`localhost" PROCEDURE "BeginTestRun" ...
```

Or :

```
CREATE DEFINER=[root`@`localhost] PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] ...
```

**Second** DEFINER is aspecific MySQL terms/object that ISO SQL Standard does not know, nor Microsoft SQL Server. The equivalent in the standard ISO SQL is the owner of the objects that is automatically associated to the SQL user that execute the CREATE statement.  So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun` ...
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "BeginTestRun" ...
```

**Third**, every variables must be prefixed with a "@" (arobas / at sign). So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
```

Must be rewrite :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] (@StartTime DATETIME, @TestJobId INT)
```

**Fourth**, DATETIME is an obsolete datatype and it would be preferable to use DATETIME2. So

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] (@StartTime DATETIME2, @TestJobId INT)
```

**Fith**, LAST_INSERT_ID() does not exists in SQL Server and must be replaced by SCOPE_IDENTITY(). So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (`id`,`StartTime`, `TestJobId`)
  VALUES (NULL,StartTime,TestJobId);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] (@StartTime DATETIME2, @TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (id, StartTime, TestJobId)
  VALUES (NULL, @StartTime, @TestJobId);
  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

**Sixth**, because SQL Server procedures are created by default in a debug mode, you must prefer to add the SET NOCOUNT ON statement to avoid untimely messages during operation. So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (`id`,`StartTime`, `TestJobId`)
  VALUES (NULL,StartTime,TestJobId);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] (@StartTime DATETIME2, @TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (id, StartTime, TestJobId)
  VALUES (NULL, @StartTime, @TestJobId);
  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

**Seventh**, when your table as an IDENTITY column, by default you cannot INSERT any value inside. So, if your column id in the table TestRuns is an IDENTITY, you should not specify this column in the list of insert target columns. So :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BeginTestRun`(StartTime DATETIME, TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (`id`,`StartTime`, `TestJobId`)
  VALUES (NULL,StartTime,TestJobId);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Must be rewrite as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BeginTestRun] (@StartTime DATETIME2, @TestJobId INT)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO TestRuns (StartTime, TestJobId)
  VALUES (@StartTime, @TestJobId);
  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Of course, the best way is to learn Transact SQL !

Answer (score 2):

> Errors: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

I imagine that the `id` column in this table is an identity, which means the following code should work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateVersion @varName varchar(100), @Version varchar(100), @TargetId INT
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Versions(Name,Version,TargetId)
  VALUES (@varName,@Version,@TargetId);
  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertId;
END
```

Comment: Aaah so this is how it should look like in MSSQL right? :)

Comment: That's right. I imagine that your conversion tool is not smart enough to work that out. It would help if you posted the code that it generated.